# Why this script does'nt work on mobile devices like android, iphone, ipad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube

I am trying to play this script on mobile devices like android, iphone, and ipad but it doesn't work.

Only playlist shows but main video shows blank ...

Please reference [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7twWb/48/)

```
// code
```

Comment: Which Script doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The player requires Flash which isn't available on those devices.

Comment: So how can i used this script on those devices. any other options.?

Comment: If you refer to the blog that this plugin comes from it informs you that there is a new way of doing this that works on mobile devices. It does not give you the exact functionality but it explains how to use iFrame embeds. The page is here:http://salman-w.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/youtube-iframe-embeds-video-playlist-and-html5.html